# Inserting records only with data (wtihout null record)

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a class, but variable A,B has value and C is null ,how can i insert that class to database without variable C ?

```
class Example
{
   public string A {get; set;}
   public string B {get; set;}
   public string C {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you're currently using to insert the class to your database so we can help show you how to not insert a property if it's `null`.

Comment: Database.Insert(ObjectExample), but this way im inserting null variable

Comment: @TomAlwson what library are you using?

Comment: Please update the question with the relevant code (not in the comments). Also please show the type declaration for `Database`.